# Way to add overlay when I am recording a Video in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-recording, camera-roll

Is there any way to add overlay while I am recording a Video so that when I will play the video from camera roll I can see the overlay.

Comment: Had any luck with your requirement? How did you add overlay to the output video while recording? If you are successful, can you share?

Answer (score 0):

easy

create a view:

```
UIView * tempView = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame...
```

then **ADD AS SUBVIEW** to your "camera ViewController":

- playerViewController
- cameraViewController
- (or any view you are using)

for example:

```
[self.playerViewController addSubView:tempView];
```

done √

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add overlays on a recorded video, please check out this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

If you also want the overlay to appear during the recording of the video, you would have to add the overlay as a subview to the `UIImagePickerController`'s `cameraOverlayView`. Take a look at this tutorial to see more: http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821

Comment: I previously tried this tutorial but in this tutorial shown that how to add overlay on a recorded video but my requirement is bit different. I want to add overlay while recording the video.

Comment: @GobindaDas - Take a look at my edits in the answer. It will cover your needs.

Comment: @"Simon Degn": Sorry but My actual requirement is the overlay which is appearing while I am recording the video, is also saved with in the video so that when I play this saved video from camera roll the overlay will appear on the video same as it was appeared at the time of recording. If I am unable to clear my requirement please let me know.